# Location of re-open questions

Tags: support, review, reopen-closed

A question of mine on Stack Exchange's Writing Beta forum was put on hold, as someone marked it as a request for critique.

Now, it kinda was, but I thought it was okay since a previous question of mine was critiqued. So, I edited it hoping it would be reopened, as that was what I learned from reading around on Meta. I read that if I edited it, it would go to the re-open queue.

Now, that's fantastic, but I can't seem to find it.

Where **is** the re-open queue? Am I, as a simple question asker, not allowed to visit the re-open queue?

If so I understand, but I'd like to know so, and surely one would be able to at least see what people are commenting on it? I have searched around on Meta for something pointing at exactly where to go, but I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The review queues on all sites are under the URL [/review](https://writing.stackexchange.com/review), but as you don't yet have the reputation to do any review action, the review icon isn't added to your topbar.

[image]

You don't have to worry about users commenting on [the review](https://writing.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/14609), because if they do, you'll see them under your question. There is no *hidden* review commentary or so.

You'll have to wait a bit till the review is complete (that is, three people reviewed it) to know the outcome. If that doesn't turn out satisfactory do ask on the site's meta, https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/, because that is better suited to solve moderation disputes then this overall, network-wide meta.

Just FYI: your question here suffered from the same style issue as your Writers question: it is lacking proper line and paragraph breaks. By omitting those the text becomes one wall of characters that is hard to read and grasp. You might want to quickly rectify that before the review is finished.

Comment: On small sites, if you look at the list of recent reviewers, you can sometimes find the review by going to their profiles and seeing what they recently reviewed. By doing that, I think I might have [found the review](https://writing.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/14609).

Comment: @Laurel ah, that is a nice trick. I was trying a different approach but couldn't quickly enough diverge to it so I gave up.